# how to get the password of membership users in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership

i want to get the password from the code.how to get password from this code.i have database and code i want to know the password of membership

```
 if (Membership.ValidateUser(Login1.UserName, Login1.Password))
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(Login1.UserName, false);
        Response.Redirect("~/abc.aspx");

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The password isn't stored, only a hash of the password. This ensures that if some body gets your database the person can't figure out everyone's password..

If you want to access any specific user then you can Reset his password..

```
MembershipUser usr = Membership.GetUser(username);
string resetPwd = usr.ResetPassword();
usr.ChangePassword(resetPwd, newPassword);
```